# Hierarchical Linear Regression in Python

Tags: python, statistics, regression

I'm doing some data analysis in python and have two variables (let's call them **groupsize** and **groupsatisfaction**) and both of them are significantly and positively correlated with the outcome metric (let's call it **groupscore**). However,  **groupsize** and **groupsatisfaction** are also correlated with each other.

I now want to know if **groupsatisfaction** is still significantly correlated with **groupscore** after I control for **groupsize**. Someone suggested that I need to do a hierarchical linear regression but I can't seem to find something telling me how to do that in Python. Any pointers or references would be very welcome.

Comment: You might need to check out scipy or pandas, eg. http://aimotion.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/machine-learning-with-python-linear.html pr something else, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425640/pymc-regression-of-many-regressions or http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2014/03/17/bayesian-glms-3/